# Reason for two random numbers in DSA?

Tags: signature, authentication, dsa, schnorr-signature, eddsa

Why is the signature in DSA the way it is?

I am referring to $r$ and $k$ in the Signing-Algorithm depicted below. Is it really necessary to have both, $r$ and $s$, or would it still be secure if only one of them is used?

In the Schnorr-Signature only one random number is involved, for example.

[image]

Comment: $k$ is drawn at random. $r$ and $s$ are not, they are obtained by applying a function. So I see no more random numbers in DSA than in Schnorr Signature.

Comment: Sorry, I confused $s$ with $k$. So my question essentially is: why could the signature not be $s:=H(m)+xr$  or $s:=k^{-1}(H(m)+x)$?

Comment: Well, both those alternatives you listed would allow easy forgery.  For the first one, given a valid signature, the attacker knows $s, H(m), r$, so they can easily recover the private key $x$.  For the second one, the validation formula is $r^s = g^{H(m)}g^x$; from a valid signature, the attacker can recover $g^x$.  Then, to forge a signature to message $m'$, he just sets $r = g^{H(m')}g^x$ and $s= 1$

Answer (score 1):

> So my question essentially is: why could the signature not be $s=H(m)+xr$ or $s=k^{−1}(H(m)+x)$?

Well, both those alternatives would allow an easy forgery after a single valid signature (or the public key in the second case)

For $s=H(m)+xr$, the adversary with a valid message/signature pair knows $s, H(m), r$.  With that, simple algebra allows him to recover $x$, the private key (and with that, he can sign anything).

For $s=k^{−1}(H(m)+x)$, the validation formula (because $r=g^k$) is $g^{ks} = r^s = g^{H(m)+x} = g^{H(m)}g^x$.  With a single valid message/signature pair, the adversary knows $r, s, H(m)$ (and $g$); that allows him to recover the value $g^x$ (alternatively, if the adversary has the public key, that's $g^x$, so the attacker might not even need a valid signature).

Then, to sign a message $m'$, the adversary can compute $r = g^{H(m')}g^x$ and $s=1$ - it is easy to see that satisfies the validation formula.